# How to change vertex style

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs, automata

I wanted final states to be the same size as non-final states. The only difference between finals and non-finals should be the existence of the double circle in the final states.

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the code:

```
              \documentclass{article}
               \usepackage{geometry}
              \usepackage{tikz}
               \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
chains,
fit,
positioning,
quotes}

                    \begin{document}
                \begin{center}
                   \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
    start chain = going right,
    arr/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners, -Straight Barb},
    N/.style = {draw, circle, fill=none, minimum size=1pt, outer sep=3pt,
        font=\tiny},
    EN/.style = {circle, draw,double,double distance=1.5pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.1pt,
        fit={#1}, node contents={}},
    every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
    ]
    % position the nodes a...d
    \coordinate[label=left:I] (a);
    \node (b) [N, right=of a] {$q_1$};
    \node (c) [N, above right=of b] {$q_2$};
    % position the nodes d...i
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
    \node (d) [N, below right=of c] {$q_3$};
    \foreach \i in {e, f,...,i}
    \node (\i) [N] {$q_\i$};
    \end{scope}
    \node (ei) [EN=(i)];
    \path   (a) edge                    (b)
    (b) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (c)
    (c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (d)
    (d) edge["0"]               (e)
    (e) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (f)
    (f) edge["0"]               (g)
    (g) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (h)
    (h) edge["1"]               (ei)
    ;
    \draw[arr]  (ei) |- ([yshift=45mm] b.north west)
    to ["$\varepsilon$" '] (b.north west);
    %%%%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
    \node (j) [N, above right=of c] {$q_j$};
    \foreach \i in {k, l, m}
    \node (\i) [N] {$q_\i$};
    \end{scope}
    \node (em) [EN=(m)];
    \path   (c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (j)
    (j) edge["1"]               (k)
    (k) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (l)
    (l) edge["0"]               (em);
    \draw[arr]  (em) |- ([yshift=42mm] b.north)
    to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
    %%%%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
    \node (n) [N, below right=of b] {$q$};
    \foreach \i in {o, p,...,s}
    \node (\i) [N] {$q_\i$};
    \end{scope}
    \node (es) [EN=(s)];
    \path   (b) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (n)
    (n) edge["0"]               (o)
    (o) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (p)
    (p) edge["1"]               (q)
    (q) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (r)
    (r) edge["0"]               (es);
    \draw[arr]  (es) |- ([yshift=-22mm] b.south)
    to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
         \end{document}
```

This is the output I got (with triple circle at final states):

[image]

Comment: Please check your MWE. Currently, it contains two documents.

Comment: As I see, you use my answer, but why than you not accept it? It is not entirely clear, what is your problem. If you like to change size of last node, please correct style of `EN` accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you may liked (or you after) the following solution

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners, -Straight Barb},
     N/.style = {circle, draw, fill=none, minimum size=1em, 
                 outer sep=3pt, font=\tiny},
    EN/.style = {N, double, double distance=1.5pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
                    ]
% position the nodes a...d
\coordinate[label=left:I] (a);
\node (b) [N, right=of a] {$q_1$};
\node (c) [N, above right=of b] {$q_2$};
% position the nodes d...i
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node (d) [N, below right=of c] {$q_3$};
\foreach \i in {e, f,...,h}
\node (\i) [N] {$q_\i$};
    \end{scope}
\node (ei) [EN, right=of h] {$q_i$};
\path   (a) edge                    (b)
(b) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (c)
(c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (d)
(d) edge["0"]               (e)
(e) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (f)
(f) edge["0"]               (g)
(g) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (h)
(h) edge["1"]               (ei)
;
\draw[arr]  (ei) |- ([yshift=45mm] b.north west)
to ["$\varepsilon$" '] (b.north west);
%%%%
\node (j) [N, above right=of c] {$q_j$};
\node (k) [N, right=of j] {$q_k$};
\node (l) [N, right=of k] {$q_l$};
\node (m) [N, right=of l] {$q_m$};
\node (em) [EN, right=of l] {$q_m$};
\path   (c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (j)
        (j) edge["1"]               (k)
        (k) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (l)
        (l) edge["0"]               (em);
\draw[arr]  (em) |- ([yshift=42mm] b.north)
                 to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
%%%%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node (n) [N, below right=of b] {$q$};
\foreach \i in {o, p,...,r}
\node (\i) [N] {$q_\i$};
    \end{scope}
\node (es) [EN, right=of r] {$q_s$};
\path   (b) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (n)
        (n) edge["0"]               (o)
        (o) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (p)
        (p) edge["1"]               (q)
        (q) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (r)
        (r) edge["0"]               (es);
\draw[arr]  (es) |- ([yshift=-22mm] b.south)
                 to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```